# Azure func not able to listen from 2 subscription in parallel

Tags: azureservicebus, subscription, azure-servicebus-topics

I have to create another subscription for service bus and then read payloads and store in another container.
I have copied the same function for Subscription A and then created one for B where i have changed
the local.settings.json "subscription_name":"subscription2".
In the python script i have made changes to the target container.

For some reason the payloads are not listened from the newly created subscription.
Anything i am missing
???

Comment: Do i need to create Shared access policies for each subscription as Listen , because only 1 for topic is working for 1 subscriber

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.